# Remove link to terms page when printing taxonomy term on node--content_type.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a node--content_type.tpl.php template where I want to print the taxonomy term associated with the current content as plain text so that I can surround it with a div class to print a special label for content with the selected term.

So for example I have chosen "Sold" as a taxonomy term and want to display the word with no link to the taxonomy terms page. It currently outputs as "<*a* datatype="" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" typeof="skos:Concept" href="/taxonomy/term/6">Sold", so links to the taxonomy terms page.

I am currently using this code to print the term:

```
<?php

if(!empty($node->field_p_status['und'][0]['value'])) {
  $status = $node->field_p_status['und'][0]['value'];
}

?>

<?php if(isset($status)) { ?>

<?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_p_status', array('label'=>'hidden'))); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Any idea how to strip it down so it prints just "Sold"?

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

To print the raw value you can use this code:

```
<?php

if(!empty($node->field_p_status['und'][0]['value'])) {
  print $node->field_p_status['und'][0]['value'];
}
?>
```

Comment: It didn't seem to print for some reason. Please see my answer below... (Thank you by the way).

Answer (score 1):

I used a different solution which was better for me by printing the id of the taxonomy term (which I then wrapped in a div class). Obviously that didn't technically print the taxonomy term itself, but allowed me to have a class where I could style a background image unique to that class to show to the user (a Sold banner).

The code I used was:

```
                    <?php

                        if(!empty($node->field_p_status['und'][0]['value'])) {
                            $status = $node->field_p_status['und'][0]['value'];
                        }

                    ?>

                    <?php if(isset($status)) { ?>

                        <div class="status_<?php print $node->field_p_status[$node->language][0]['tid'] ?>"></div>

                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It is good to have found the answer ;-)